# SQL BETWEEN statement not returning any results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull out longitude and latitude values from my database (stored as decimal(10,6)  ) between a range of two values, but for some reason one of the values isn't returning any results.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE location_latitude BETWEEN 53.76200 AND 53.765000 AND location_longitude BETWEEN -2.710000 AND -2.720000
```

When I query just the latitude, I get results back fine. The issue seems to lie with just the longitude. I'm still fairly new to all this, but could it have something to do with the minus symbol before the longitude values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Datatype for location_latitude and location_longitude???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of the parameters on the `BETWEEN`:

```
AND location_longitude BETWEEN -2.720000 AND -2.710000
```

Since `-2.72` is less than `-2.71`

Comment: Can you please show a proof for this?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Nope

Comment: Fantastic, have 10 rep.

Answer (score 1):

`location_longitude BETWEEN -2.710000 AND -2.720000` returns true iff -2.71 <= longitude <= -2.72. The expression always returns false because -2.72 < -2.71. Switch the two values.

[BETWEEN documentation for MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: While you are correct and `BETWEEN` works like this both in SQL-Server and MySQL and as it should work (by the standard), the question is tagged with `[tag:mysql]`, not with `[tag:sql-server]`. Perhaps you can provide a link to the mysql documentation.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for catching that.